# Bash file that executes a python script with arguments

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a python script with 4 arguments. The last argument needs to be in single quotes. I have a txt/csv file that has the arguments stored in form of plaintext. I want to run it using a bash script. I got errors while parsing the single quote as bash doesn't recognize the single quote in the form of input argument.

There are going to be 4 columns in the text file:

Text/CSV File:

```
Col1 Col2               Col3 Col4 
ABC  C:\nihar\document3 abc  'jkl' 
DEF  C:\nihar\document2 d3f  'opq' 
123  C:\nihar\document1 a89  '012'
```

(in text format, the seperator will be spaces, where as in csv, it'll be comma)

NOTE: Col3 and Col4 also has special characters in them.

```
bash file:
         ./testpython.py $A $B $C $D

where $A = Col1, $B = Col2, $C = Col3, $D = Col4.
```

It has a hard time recognizing the single quotes, and hence it's giving me an error, as col4 is a password, which has to be in single quotes.

PS: I can't change anything in the python file. So, the python file is supposed to stay as is.

Here's what i tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read A B C D
do
        ./testpython.py $A $B $C $D 
done < file.csv
```

Also tried these for the 4th line:

```
./testpython.py $A $B $C \'$D\'
./testpython.py $A $B $C "'$D'"
./testpython.py $A $B $C "$D"
./testpython.py $A $B $C ''$D''
```

When i replace $D with the actual value i.e. 'jkl', it works.
When i attempt to execute my script, the single quotes that i need are not showing up for that column. If that value is not in single quotes, the python script wont work.

Comment: Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/; you'll see that it tells you to use syntactic quotes (as opposed to literal ones) for **all** your expansions. Thus: `./testpython.py "$A" "$B" "$C" "$D"`

Comment: `sed 1d file.csv | xargs -n 4 ./testpython.py`?

Comment: @Cyrus, ...insofar as the OP is saying they have other unusual characters in the file, exposing it to `xargs` is probably a bad idea. In a scenario where neither `-0` or `-d` is appropriate, the sorta-like-a-shell-but-not parsing that xargs performs is unlikely to be the Right Thing.

Comment: @NiharMehta, ...by the way -- it would be helpful if you showed us a complete and exact example (vs a description that can potentially be interpreted multiple ways) of how you invoke your `testpython.py` with a shell when it actually works. If you run `./testpython ABC C:/nihar/document1 abc 'jkl'`, for example, in that case the single-quotes around `jkl` are never given to Python at all, but consumed by the shell as syntax; if you `print(repr(sys.argv))` in Python, you'll see that (in that specific usage mode) there are no literal quotes in the string at all.

Comment: @NiharMehta, ...similarly, it would be helpful to collect the log from a shell with `set -x` previously run for both the known-working (presumably, interactive-usage?) case and the known-broken case (to run a shell script in that mode, run `bash -x yourscript`).

Comment: @NiharMehta, ...that said, note that `set -x` in shell adds extra syntax for display purposes, in the same way `repr(...)` does in Python; thus, when `set -x` changes `foo bar` to `'foo bar'` or `foo\ bar`, that doesn't mean it actually changed your data to add quotes or backslashes; instead, the quotes or backslashes are just part of how a string with a literal space in it are represented in a shell literal.

Comment: You need to make a [mcve]. To start, what do you mean by "special characters"? Symbols? Control characters?

Comment: The problem seems to be that you're not familiar with literal characters vs shell syntax, but writing an answer is difficult since we can't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash, always quote variables.

Using your data file and the following stand-in for your Python program:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
count = 0
for arg in sys.argv:
    print('arg {}: <{}>'.format(count, arg))
    count+=1
```

and modifying your Bash script like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while read -r a b c d
do
    if ((count++)) # skip the first line of the csv file
    then
        printf -- '--- line %d ---\n' "$count"
        ./testpython.py "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d"
    fi
done < file.csv
```

I get the following output:

```
--- line 2 ---
arg 0: <./args.py>
arg 1: <ABC>
arg 2: <C:\nihar\document3>
arg 3: <abc>
arg 4: <'jkl'>
--- line 3 ---
arg 0: <./args.py>
arg 1: <DEF>
arg 2: <C:\nihar\document2>
arg 3: <d3f>
arg 4: <'opq'>
--- line 4 ---
arg 0: <./args.py>
arg 1: <123>
arg 2: <C:\nihar\document1>
arg 3: <a89>
arg 4: <'012'>
```

which shows the single quotes around the contents of column 4.

Additional notes:

- Use `-r` almost always with `read` (in this case it preserves the backslashes in your Windows paths).
- Use lowercase or mixed case variable names in order to avoid possible collisions with shell or environment variables
- In your real script, use meaningful variable names
- If you're trying to read passwords, you will have problems using this technique if the passwords may contain the field delimiter in your input file and quite likely if they may contain single quotes.
- Note that even if I leave out the quotes around `$d` I still get the single quotes in my Python file